# Rails is error after install Android SDK

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, sdk

last time, i was installing Android SDK, and now when i'm creating rubyonrails i get some notification,

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:254: warning: Insecure world writable dir /root/android-sdk-linux in PATH, mode 040757
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:263: warning: Insecure world writable dir /root/android-sdk-linux in PATH, mode 040757

what's wrong? help me please? Thanks's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing related with rails here. Check if you are creating a new app in a dir where you have permissions.